# If in_array not using specified template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The purpose is to create a separate theme for products in woocommerce. I created a folder called woocommerce and put it in my theme directory. The 2 files required are single-product.php and content-single-product.php which I placed in the woocommerce folder. I then duplicated both of these files but named them single-product-mtg.php and content-single-product-mtg.php.

Next, I edited the original single-product.php and replaced this code:

```
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
```

with this code:

```
global $post;

            $terms      = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
            $categories = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' );

            if (in_array( 'mtg', $categories ) ) {
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-mtg' );
            } else {
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
            } // end of new specfic category code ?>
```

When I dump $terms I get this:

```
array(1) 
{ 
[0]=> object(WP_Term)#2832 (10) 
    { 
    ["term_id"]=> int(28) ["name"]=> string(19) "Magic the Gathering" 
    ["slug"]=> string(3) "mtg" 
    ["term_group"]=> int(0) 
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(28) 
    ["taxonomy"]=> string(11) "product_cat" 
    ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["parent"]=> int(0) 
    ["count"]=> int(295) 
    ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
    }
 }
```

When I dump $categories I get this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "mtg" }
```

However, instead of the code using content-single-product-mtg.php as is intended, it keeps using content-single-product.php. What am I doing wrong and how do I get this to use content-single-product-mtg.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a custom theme, I forgot to add woocommerce support in functions. Works fine now. Anyone else curious or comes by same problem you can add this to your theme's functions.php file.

```
function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce', array(
    'thumbnail_image_width' => 150,
    'single_image_width'    => 300,

    'product_grid'          => array(
        'default_rows'    => 3,
        'min_rows'        => 2,
        'max_rows'        => 8,
        'default_columns' => 4,
        'min_columns'     => 2,
        'max_columns'     => 5,
    ),
) );
```

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );